# I need to ReStructure my render body part of layout view in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, layout

I have a Layout page in my MVC Website project Now the problem is that in a certain page i want that the series of links appear at the top in that render content portion of the layout view page.

But I have tried all other mehods to remove the padding space at the top but none of them worked.It yet shows the large amount of empty space at the top which i don't need.I'll Place the snapshot image of the view page.

Below is my Layout Page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>_LoginLayout</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1" style="width:100%;font-family:Arial;border-collapse:collapse">
        <tr style="height:140px">
            <td align="center"><img src="~/Images/nurseimage.jpg" /></td> <td style="text-align:center"><h1 style="color:red">Doctor Appointment Booking</h1>    <img src="~/Images/Hospitallogo.jpeg" /></td>                                                                                                       
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:420px">
            <td style="width:30%"><h3>Image Part</h3></td>
            <td style="width:70%;margin-top:-120px">@RenderBody()</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:50px">
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;font-size:x-small">
                <h3>Copyright at XYZ</h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Dynamic content View:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>PatientHomePage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr style="padding:-30px">
            <th style="padding-top:-20px"><a href="~/Views/Login/PatientHomePage.cshtml">Book Appointments</a></th>
            <th><a href="">View Bookings</a></th>
            <th><a href="">Cancel Bookings</a></th>
            <th><a href="">Search Doctor</a></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td colspan="5"><img src="~/Images/PatientLogo.png" /></td>  
         <td colspan="2"><h1>Welcome </h1></td>   
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

and it's snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `<Doctype>` ,`<head>`, `<body>` tags in your view page.. Since its there in Layout page its served as the master page. All you want is to have just the the content that you need to place inside your

`<td style="width:70%;margin-top:-120px">@RenderBody()</td>`

Explaining it in detail.. You see the part `@RenderBody()` right. This is a place holder that will be replaced with the content of your view. So when the final view is returned from your application to the browser it is combination of the Layout page + your view (placed in the location where it finds `@RenderBody()`).

So now you understand that when this combination happens you have a HTML page in which there is a table and a tr which again contains the HTML page (with DOCtype, head, body tags). So that's invalid HTML in the first place, Also there might be some CSS that is causing the margin-top issue for you.

To fix it, All you need in your `Dynamic content View:` is as below.

```
   <table>
        <tr style="padding:-30px">
            <th style="padding-top:-20px"><a href="~/Views/Login/PatientHomePage.cshtml">Book Appointments</a></th>
            <th><a href="">View Bookings</a></th>
            <th><a href="">Cancel Bookings</a></th>
            <th><a href="">Search Doctor</a></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td colspan="5"><img src="~/Images/PatientLogo.png" /></td>  
         <td colspan="2"><h1>Welcome </h1></td>   
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**More Info**: You can inspect the element (`right click on the UI that you need to debug and choose Inspect element`) and find out what styles have been applied on it and easily track the styles that is causing the issue

Comment: You are telling me that don't include head and body tag in this view so then how would i be able to define style tag for some elements on this content view?btw thanks for your response

Comment: @KamalSingh yes you dont have to include it. And style tags can go anywhere in your html.. Remember it as just any other html tag. you can place it anywhere in your html content, even you can keep it in a .css file and reference the file in your page. As a best practice people would recommend to place the style tags in head tag, There is a way to do that in MVC (using render sections in layout page http://dotnet-stuff.com/tutorials/aspnet-mvc/exploring-layouts-renderbody-rendersection-and-renderpage-in-asp-net-mvc). So as said its just a coding standard and not mandatory.

Comment: rest everything is good except the main problem i listed still not found anything that can make use of that empty space there!

Comment: did you inspect and see what is taking up space?

Comment: Luckily i found out the solution by placing a very special attribut in the tr of the layout page table called valign and set that to top which did the job for me!

Comment: Good. nice to know it fixed, So thats the issue.. As its a table by default the content are placed in the center of the cell.. using valign you can place it in top